# How to configure apple push notification?

Tags: java, ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Currently i have coded according to Certificate.P12 file.
like this:

```
PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationBigPayload.complex();
                    payload.getMaximumPayloadSize();
                    payload.addAlert(data.getString("message"));
                    payload.addBadge(1);
                    payload.addSound("default");
                    payload.addCustomDictionary("data", data);

List<PushedNotification> NOTIFICATIONS = new ArrayList<PushedNotification>();
File file = new File(p12FilePath, "Certificates.p12");
NOTIFICATIONS.addAll(Push.payload(payload, file, "password", true, deviceList));
```

So how to configure this with P8. certificate file.
IOS has provided and i have "KeyId", "Bundle Id", "Team ID".
so what changes i need to do for configuring with P8 certificate file?